Can a Ruthenian Catholic incur automatic excommunication for apostasy?
Can a member of the Ruthenian Catholic Church be automatically excommunicated for apostasy?  As far as I know they can't be, as the Code of Canons of the Eastern Churches states:

"One who denies a truth which must be believed with divine and catholic faith, or who calls it into doubt, or who totally repudiates the Christian faith, and does not retract it after having been legitimately warned, is to be punished as a heretic or an apostate with a major excommunication" (1436)

Does this imply that the Church has to be officially involved in order for the person to be excommunicated?

In the law of the Eastern Catholic Churches there is no automatic excommuncation (poena latae sententiae). The Codex Canonum Ecclesiarum Orientalum says on all penalities in can. 1408 CCEO:

Poena reum non tenet, nisi postquam sententia vel decreto irrogata est, salvo iure Romani Pontificis vel Concilii Oecumenici aliter statuendi.

In English:

A penalty does not bind the guilty party before it has been imposed by a sentence or decree, without prejudice to the right of the Roman Pontiff or an Ecumenical Council to determine otherwise.

This is a difference to the law of the Latin Church (can. 1314 CIC). It is an argument in the intensive canonistic discussion, whether penalities laetae sententiae really are good idea (in our modern times): in 1983 Pope John-Paul II. believed it necessary for the Latin Church, in 1990 he believed the Eastern Catholic Churches can live without it.
As answer to the question: An Eastern Catholic cannot be automatically excommunicated as in his law penalities latae sententiae do not exist. The competent authority needs to carry out a penal process to incur upon him the legal consequence of his apostasy or heresy. Albeit on a spiritual and social side apostasy, heresy and schism stay offences through that one dislodges oneself from the Church.
